# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, attributeerror, kivymd, getattr

I'm learning KivyMD and I'm trying to add a dropdown menu but I get this error. It's probably because of my wrong usage of ids but I still cant figure it out. Here is my main py code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 800)

class HomePage(Screen):
    pass

class SecondPage(Screen):
    pass

class App(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        items_d = ['Settings', 'Profile', 'Log Out', 'Exit']
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f"{i}",
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "height": dp(40),
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in items_d
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller = self.screen.ids.tool1,
            items = menu_items,
            width_mult =2
        )

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        print(text_item)
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '500'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomePage(name='first'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondPage(name='second'))

        return self.screen
    

App().run()
```

and here is the kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

ScreenManager:
    HomePage:
    SecondPage:

<HomePage>
    name: 'first'

    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'

                    MDTopAppBar:
                        id:tool1
                        title: 'Home Page'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                        right_action_items: [['dots-vertical'], lambda x: app.menu.open()]
                        elevation: 3

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "."

                    MDBottomAppBar:
                        MDTopAppBar:
                            icon: 'apps'
                            mode: 'center'
                            type: 'bottom'
                            

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Home Page'
                        on_press: nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'first'

                        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon:'bluetooth'

                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Content Page'
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'
                        on_press: nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                                
                        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon:'content-copy'


<SecondPage>
    name: 'second'

    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'

                    MDTopAppBar:
                        id:tool1
                        title: 'Content Page'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                        right_action_items: [['dots-vertical'], lambda x: app.menu.open()]
                        elevation: 3

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "."

                    MDBottomAppBar:
                        MDTopAppBar:
                            type: 'bottom'
                            icon: 'apps'
                            mode: 'center'
                            left_action_items: [['information']]

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Home Page'
                        on_press: nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'first'

                        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon:'bluetooth'

                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Second Page'
                        on_press: nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'

                        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon:'wifi'
```

I don't know why exactly but maybe because of self.screen doesn't really contain the ids?
And please tell me what to use instead if I'm using wrong methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly trying to access the `tool1` `id`. First, note that the `ids` defined in the `kv` file become part of the `ids` dictionary of the root of the rule where that `id` is defined. So the `tool1` `id` (which is defined twice) ends up in the `ids` of the `HomePage` and also in the `ids` of the `SecondPage`. So you must reference that `id` through the containing object. Assuming you want to reference the `tool1` defined in `HomePage`, just change:

```
caller = self.screen.ids.tool1,
```

to:

```
caller = self.screen.get_screen('first').ids.tool1,
```

Unrelated, but you can eliminate the lines:

```
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(HomePage(name='first'))
    sm.add_widget(SecondPage(name='second'))
```

since their result is unused.

Comment: Thank you, I'm no longer getting that error. But instead I'm getting a TypeError like: object of type 'function' has no len(). do you know what else is wrong in the code? I would be grateful

Comment: Another question should be posted as a separate question.